# Pre-edge spell to bypass force

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

If I have 6 magic and 8 spellcasting with 4 edge and I wish to cast a spell that has some pretty high drain value, is it possible to use push the limit [pre-edge] the spell cast at force 1 and only have to resist the drain of the force 1 spell with no limits on the spell?

That way I would be rolling [6magic+8spellcast+4edge] 18 dice on a spell cast with no limit, and basically no drain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, you can do that.

That is one of the problems with the new limit system for spells.
But you are also limited by your **Edge** pool. And the higher your *Edge* is, better results you will obtain.

Keep in mind that using force 1 isn't really a good idea unless the spell has a DV (*Drain Value*) of F+1 or higher, as the minimum DV is always 2, so aim for 2DV and not 1 DV or less (ex: manabolt is F-3), as you won't really benefit from it.

However, it isn't really something exploitable, as many spells *depend* on the force being used. So, using a low force spell, even if you get many successes, won't necessarily mean that your spell is stronger using this method.

- Combat spells

  - Direct spells: These will benefit the most from using **LFHE** (low force, high edge), as their usefulness depends almost entirely on the successes you got (*net hits*) against the target's Body (for physical) or Willpower (for mana);
  - Indirect spells: The damage on indirect spells, which first you must *hit* with a check against the target's Reaction+Intuition, is *directly* based on the force used plus *net hits*. Meaning that each point of force you reduce is one less damage it will cause, so it's a 1-by-1 trade, 1 damage for 1 drain. However, not only that, these spells also got an AP (armor penetration) equal to the force used, so you will actually cause less damage against armored targets.
- Detection spells

  - Range: The first thing to notice here is that both the standard and extended range of your spells will be affected. Standard being Force * Magic in meters, and extended being 10 times that distance. So when casting a detection spell using *LFHE* you will get a much shorter range (ex: force 1/magic 6 = 6 meters, while force 6/magic 6 = 36 meters) on your *detection* spells, kind of defeating the purpose of many of them. The extended version spells like *Detect Enemies* will actually benefit from this, as even the shorter range is actually pretty good (60 meters), and instead of eating 6 DV drain, you will only take 2 DV (again, the minimum drain value).
  - *Net hits*: Most detection spells depend solely on the *net hits* obtained, gaining more information for each additional success, so using *LFHE* is actually a good idea here if the shorter range isn't an issue.
- Health spells

  - Only one spell (on the core) is really dependant on the force used, Increase [Attribute]. The Force must be equal or higher than the current (augmented) value of the attribute you want to increase, So if you are trying to increase a troll's strength of 8, you need to use Force 8+, with each hit increasing his strength by 1 point (up to the augmented maximum);
  - There is also *Stabilize* and *Detox*, but at F-4 drain, Stabilize won't really benefit from *LFHE*, as casting it at F6 will still cause 2 DV. For Detox, the spell force must be equal to or higher than the toxin's base DV (damage value), but at F-6, you will rarely need to use *LFHE* with Detox, as the toxins that require a Force higher than 6 will already make you take physical drain and using *LFHE* becomes pointless;
- Illusion spells

  - All illusion spells are entirely dependant on net hits, with force merely defining your limit and drain value.
- Manipulation spells

  - Mental spells: These spells will suffer if you use *LFHE*, as they cause a penalty on the resistance check (logic+willpower) equal to the force being used. So, a force 1 spell will only cause a -1 penalty on the check and will be easier to resist;
  - Damaging spells: These will cause less damage if you use a lower force, but keep in mind that manipulation spells should never be your primary option for damaging enemies. Also, your *net hits* on these spells won't affect the damage at all. Fling, however, doesn't really care about the force used (you need successes to hit your target), as it will use your Magic attribute to define the damage caused.
  - Movement and weight: Some manipulation spells will increase the speed of the effect based on the force used. Spells like Levitate will move the subject slower when cast at force 1, 1 meter per second. While Fling will affect the weight of the object you can throw around, 1kg per force. (Protip: I had a force 2 Levitate nearly 24/7 during missions sustained by a focus)
  - Barriers: The size of all your barriers is affected by the force of the spell. Normally, force * 2 meters for length and force meters for height. Which means that, at force 3, you can still create a small Physical Barrier that will block a corridor, 6x3 meters with F-1 drain value, which is a pretty good deal.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** this is possible.

Also because of the *Rule-Of-Six* the expected number of hits (before applying the limit in case of non-edging) from \$\frac{D}{3}\$ to \$\frac{2 D}{5}\$, where \$D\$ is the number of dice used.

You can also "pay money" for similar effects regarding the limit instead, by using Reagents (SR5, p. 317) which lets you use the number of reagents used as limit instead.

Note however, that you don't increase the force of the spell by using edge. Some spell effects depend on the force, not on the hits. E.g.:

- If you get a incredibly lucky roll, you may be able to levitate a bus, but you still cannot ram a mobile target with it, since the movement rate depends on the force.
- You may create a very durable barrier, but this doesn't increase the size of the barrier beyond the limits caused by the force.
- The AP of indirect combat spells is not modified and the damage is still *Force + Net Hits*.